# Django get the value of foreignId from django.contrib.auth.models User

Tags: django, django-models

I have created a model which has foreign key to the `django.contrib.auth.models` `User` model. I need to retrieve the value the foreign key is referring to. But how to do that?

E.g. my model is

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
def FooModel(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

then I know I can either use:

`FooModel.objects.get()` or `FooModel.objects.filter()` but as far as I know they will only return entries from the FooModel only. So how do I retrieve from the `User` model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m = FooModel.objects.get(id=123434)
m.user.username
```

You can use `.`.That wxample will return you the username of the related user. Also you can create `joins` using `__` on the query filtering. Like:

```
FooModel.objects.get(user__username='Foo')
```

But, since you are building your query on `FooModel`, you will always get `FooModel` results. So you have you use `.` to use foreignkey relations to get to the required `User` field.

EDIT:

Django also allows you to use `reverse relations` on querysets, so even though `User` model do not have a foreignkey to `FooModel` on its model structure, you can use reverse relation of `Foomodel.user` foreignkey like:

```
def FooModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    foofield = Models.CharField(...)



User.objects.get(foomodel__foofield='Beatles')
```

will return you the user which have `FooModel` record with a foreign key to his `User` record and foofield value of *Beatles*

Answer (score 0):

You can access foreign key ids by referencing the property name + `_id`. For example: `yourmodel.user_id`

Comment: Yes I know that one, but I would like to get the username. E.g. if I used SQL query I would join FooTable with the UserTable WHERE foreignkey = id. Something like that, so I can access the username